# Xamarin to Maui - OnPlatform.iOS is not found

Tags: maui

I have a Xamarin app that I am trying to convert into Maui. I am looking into my Resource files at the moment and I am unsure how to covert platform-specific resources into Maui.
This is my xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="Mobile.Framework.UI.Themes.HeightRequestResourceDictionary">

  <OnPlatform x:Key="NormalButtonHeightRequest" x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
    <OnPlatform.iOS>36</OnPlatform.iOS>
    <OnPlatform.Android>42</OnPlatform.Android>
  </OnPlatform>
 </ResourceDictionary>
```

The compiler complains about OnPlatform.iOS saying it is not found in OnPlatform.

This is the code behind:
namespace Mobile.Framework.UI.Themes;

```
public partial class HeightRequestResourceDictionary : ResourceDictionary
{
    public HeightRequestResourceDictionary()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

I know that in Maui we have this new folder called Platform where I might need to move this logic in?? I don't know.

The only thing I have changed is removing a reference to Xamarin.Form in the code behind and change the namespaces in the xaml file.

Any help is appreciated - thank you

Comment: You may also refer to this : [Stand-alone resource dictionaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/resource-dictionaries#stand-alone-resource-dictionaries)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maui uses the newer [OnPlatform syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/xaml/fundamentals/essential-syntax#platform-differences):

```xml
<OnPlatform x:Key="NormalButtonHeightRequest" x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
    <On Platform="iOS" Value="36" />
    <On Platform="Android" Value="42" />
</OnPlatform>
```

The reason for this change, is so that new platforms can be added, simply by using additional strings. No longer requires an "enum" to be extended with each platform.